# Big O notation of a constant larger than 1

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Does it mean anything at all to have a function with time complexity O(2)?

For example, how would one describe a function that must check two lookup tables rather than one. Is that not strictly describable in big-O, or is O(2) a real way to describe this? Or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: O(n + m) with n/m being the length of the two lookup tables, respectively

Comment: Big-O notation abstracts away constant multipliers. So if your complexity can be described as `c * f(n)` for any constant value `c` with `f(n) = 1`, then you have `O(1)`

Answer (score 3):

`O(something)` is a set of functions.

`O(1)` and `O(2)` are the same set.

A constant time function is a member of `O(1)`. It's also a member of `O(2)` because `O(1)` and `O(2)` are exactly the same thing.  Use whichever one you prefer. Normally you'd use `O(1)`, but you be you.